# How to use ActiveModel callbacks on class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I want to execute a method before each class method. Is it possible to do this using ActiveModel callbacks or do i have to use metaprogramming ?

I tried :

```
class Image
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks

  define_model_callbacks :create
  before_create :set_base_uri

  def self.create
    run_callbacks :create do
      ..my_code..
    end
  end

  def set_base_uri
    ..my_code..
  end
end
```

When i call `Image.create` i get

> undefined method `run_callbacks' for Image:Class

The same code works if i change `create` to an instance method. I looked at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) but they don't mention class methods, does ActiveModel support class methods callbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think callback can work, as the callback method is invoked in the instance level. Use an alias_method may works.